# How do I simultaneously open child and sub-child of a parent, in jQuery accordion menu, when parent is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this jQuery plugin for a multilevel accordion menu: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNqvvB

I have some programming knowledge but am very new to jQuery and don't know it very well. What I want to accomplish is for the child <h4> and child <p> sections to slide open, when the parent <h3> is clicked. The original code only opens the <h4> child when <h3> parent is clicked and not the sub-child <p>.

This makes sense if the menu is being used to display multiple options at the lower child level (for instance the plugin HTML displays titles of news stories), but in my case, I am using the menu to display individual stories at the parent level and their flavor text and passage at the child level. This means making the user click on the flavor text to view the passage text doesn't make sense.

That being the case, once someone clicks the title of the story placed in <h3>, I want both the flavor text in <h4> and a passage from the story in <p> to display simultaneously on that click.

How can I accomplish this?

**jQuery**

```
var headers = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6"];

$(".accordion").click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target,
      name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

  if($.inArray(name,headers) > -1) {
    var subItem = $(target).next();

    //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
    var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
    var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div").filter(function() {
      if($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
        return true; 
      }
    });
    $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

    //slideToggle target content and adjust bottom border if necessary
    subItem.slideToggle("fast",function() {
        $(".accordion :visible:last").css("border-radius","0 0 10px 10px");
    });
    $(target).css({"border-bottom-right-radius":"0", "border-bottom-left-radius":"0"});
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<aside class="accordion">

            <h1>News</h1> 
            <div class="opened-for-codepen">
                <h2>News Item #1</h2> 
                <div class="opened-for-codepen">
                    <h3>News Item #1a</h3> 
                    <div>
                        <h4>News Subitem 1</h4> 
    <!--WOULD BECOME "Story 1 passage text"-->
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<aside class="accordion">
<!--EXAMPLE OF HOW I WANT TO USE MENU ITEMS/HEADERS--->
    <h1>News</h1><!--WOULD BECOME "Act 1"-->
    <div class="opened-for-codepen">
        <h2>News Item #1</h2><!--WOULD BECOME "Story Arc 1"-->
        <div class="opened-for-codepen">
            <!--CLICKING <H3> WOULD OPEN <H4> AND <P>-->
            <h3>News Item #1a</h3><!--WOULD BECOME "Story 1 by Author 1"-->
            <div>
                <!--WOULD OPEN WHEN <H3> IS CLICKED-->
                <h4>News Subitem 1</h4><!--WOULD BECOME "Story 1 flavor text"-->            
                <!--WOULD ALSO OPEN WHEN <H3> IS CLICKED-->
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>

            <h3>News Item #1b</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

            <h3>News Item #1c</h3>
            <div class="opened-for-codepen">
                <h4>News Subitem 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h4>News Subitem 2</h4>
                <p class="opened-for-codepen">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2>News Item #2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>News Item #3</h2>
        <div>
            <h3>News Item #3a</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

            <h3>News Item #3b</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Updates</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Update #1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>Update #2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>Update #3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>Update #4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <h1>Miscellaneous</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Misc. #1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>Misc. #2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        <h2>Misc. #3</h2>
        <div>
            <h3>Misc. Item #1a</h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Misc. Subitem 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h4>Misc. Subitem 2</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h4>Misc. Subitem 3</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Misc. Item #2a</h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Misc. Subitem 1</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h4>Misc. Subitem 2</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <h3>News Item #1b</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h4>News Subitem 1</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        <h4>News Subitem 2</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>

                    <h3>News Item #1c</h3>
                    <div class="opened-for-codepen">
                        <h4>News Subitem 1</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        <h4>News Subitem 2</h4>
                        <p class="opened-for-codepen">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h2>News Item #2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>News Item #3</h2>
                <div>
                    <h3>News Item #3a</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                    <h3>News Item #3b</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h1>Updates</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>Update #1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>Update #2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>Update #3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>Update #4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>

            <h1>Miscellaneous</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>Misc. #1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>Misc. #2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                <h2>Misc. #3</h2>
                <div>
                    <h3>Misc. Item #1a</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Misc. Subitem 1</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        <h4>Misc. Subitem 2</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        <h4>Misc. Subitem 3</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Misc. Item #2a</h3>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Misc. Subitem 1</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        <h4>Misc. Subitem 2</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.accordion {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.accordion h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordion h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: "News Cycle";
}
.accordion h1 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #1abc9c;
}
.accordion h1:hover {
  color: #4afcdc;
}
.accordion h1:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.accordion h1:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.accordion h1:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #1abc9c;
}
.accordion div, .accordion p {
  display: none;
}
.accordion h2 {
  padding: 5px 25px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #333;
}
.accordion h2:hover {
  background-color: #09ab8b;
}
.accordion h3 {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background-color: #b94152;
  font-size: .9rem;
  color: #ddd; 
}
.accordion h3:hover {
  background-color: #a93142;
}
.accordion h4 {
  padding: 5px 35px;
  background-color: #ffc25a;
  font-size: .9rem;
  color: #af720a; 
}
.accordion h4:hover {
  background-color: #e0b040;
}
.accordion p {
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: "Georgia";
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}
.accordion .opened-for-codepen {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this:

```
$('h3').click(function(){
  $(this).next('div').find('p').show();
});
```

and commented this out:

```
$(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");
```

[Here is the full code on **CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJmeP)

Seems to work for me :)

Comment: This works for me too. Thank you so much for your time and expertise!

Comment: May I have your input on another matter related to this bit of js?

What code will make it so, if the user clicks the <h3>, <h2> or <h1> to close the menu, then opens one of these again, the menus will have reverted to their closed state?

Comment: @oedalis Your initial requirement was to expand the tags when you click on _h3_. Isn't that teh opposite of what you just asked? Or didn't I understand properly?

Comment: You understood perfectly: when I click on <h3>, both <h4> and <p> open and this is precisely what I wanted. I just noticed that now, when the menu is closed, if it is opened again, the previous state is saved. After the menu gets closed, none of the menu items that were previously expanded are collapsed.

I'm unsure how to collapse them when the whole menu is closed or otherwise clear that state. I just wondered if you had any tips on handling that.

Comment: It seems I have been advised to post a new question for my question about this solution, so I will do that now.

Comment: @oedalis use `$(this).next('div').find('p').toggle();` instead of `$(this).next('div').find('p').show();` :)

Comment: Hmm that one didn't work for me. On the advice of Chad Killingsworth, I've posted my follow up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909296/how-to-collapse-all-submenus-on-closing-jquery-accordion-menu). Thank you for your help and for adding those helpful comments to the code.