# How to collapse all submenus on closing jQuery accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907928/how-do-i-simultaneously-open-child-and-sub-child-of-a-parent-in-jquery-accordio/31908398?noredirect=1#comment51732008_31908398). The solution provided by Ahs N worked great. But now when the menu is closed and opened again, the sub-items that were previously opened are still open in whatever configuration they were left. How do I clear this state but still retain the effects of the excellent solution I am using?

Comment: So you want the `p` tags to show only the first time you click on the headers and then they should always be hidden the other times the headers are clicked?

Comment: The menu already works so that if another item is clicked, it expands but others collapse. This is also the case when all menus are closed by clicking the <h1> item to close all--when it is opened again, the sub-menus begin in a collapsed state---the only exception is when the page first loads. I want to retain this functionality while still allowing the expansion of <h4> and <p> when <h3> is clicked.

Comment: So, for instance, the menu loads and the default menus are opened, but when an <h3> is clicked, <h4> and <p> expand, then when a different <h3> is clicked, the first set collapse and the new set expand, and then if <h2> is clicked, the open items close and the children for that <h2> are displayed. Same for <h1>, etc. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and seems to work according to what you asked:

```
if(name=="H3"){
      $(target).next().show().find("p, div").show();
}
```

[Here is the link to the **CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQYpE)

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts Ahs N. However the state doesn't seem to clear when I interact with the pen you linked and this makes it so that once an <h3> is clicked, it cannot be closed again.

Comment: @oedalis Sorry, i didn't notice that bug. The default code was overwriting my codes since they were being executed afterwards. I fixed the code and updated the CodePen link, please have a look at it and let me know if that solves ur problem :)

Comment: Ahs, the bug is definitely fixed, but the state is still not cleared. 
Here is the original pen to show how the state clears when the parent is closed: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNqvvB.
You can click around and open different configurations of nested menus but when a parent is closed all the children are closed too. This is seen when opening the parent again. 
The only change to this I'm looking for is for the two children H4 and P to open at the same time when H3 is clicked (and it should remain possible for H3 to close), but once H2 or H1 are closed, all the children should close again too.

Comment: @oedalis [here is the updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQYpE), apparently the code is doing a few things on its own, so no need to really control it :)

Comment: Very awesome, your help is much appreciated :D